# How to i display a str where all the items in the list belonging to a certain criteria are shown and within a range of dates?

Tags: python-3.x

So as the question said, i want to be able to display for example all items in the category of food within a range of dates. So far i tried doing this and its the only one i get with no errors but it returns none even if the date is within the range. Apologies if it is a little messy towards the end, i'm still learning how to use python

```
class ExpenditureList:
    _types = ['Food','Transport', 'Education']
    def __init__(self):
        self._expenditures = []

    @classmethod
    def ExpenditureTypes(cls):
        return cls._types

def getExpenditures(self, expenditureType, edays=0):
        startDate = date.today() - timedelta(days=edays)
        if expenditureType == 'Food':
            for item in self._expenditures:
                if item._type == ExpenditureList._types[1]:
                    for i in range(startDate, (date.today() + timedelta(days=1))):
                        if item._date == i:
                            return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filtering by one category at a time and use the fact that you can compare dates. You don't have to iterate all of possible dates:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import datetime


@dataclass
class Expenditure:
    TYPES = ["Food", "Transport", "Education"]
    type: str
    date: datetime


expenditures = [
    Expenditure("Food", datetime(1999, 1, 1)),
    Expenditure("Food", datetime(2020, 1, 1)),
    Expenditure("Transport", datetime(2000, 1, 1)),
]

food_exps = [exp for exp in expenditures if exp.type == "Food"]
old_exps = [exp for exp in expenditures if exp.date.year < 2000]
print(old_exps)

start = datetime(1999, 9, 9)
end = datetime(2001, 1, 1)
custom_date_exps = [exp for exp in expenditures if start < exp.date < end]
print(custom_date_exps)
```

If you don't know list comprehensions yet - rembember that this:

```
food_exps = [exp for exp in expenditures if exp.type == "Food"]
```

is equivalent to this:

```
food_exps = []
for exp in expenditures:
    if exp.type == "Food":
        food_exps.append(exp)
```

Anyway if you just want your version working:

```
def getExpenditures(self, expenditureType, edays=0):
    start_date = date.today() - timedelta(days=edays)
    result = []
    for item in self._expenditures:
        if item._type == expenditureType and item._date > start_date:
            result.append(item)
    return result
```

Comment: I actually tried to do list comprehensions but i'm not very good at it. Needless to say, i failed. Thanks anyway!